# opensslconf.h not found

Tags: compiling, openssl

I'm trying to build znort987's parser, and have executed `sudo apt-get libssl-dev`. I can see all sorts of ssl related header files in `/usr/include/openssl` but `opensslconf.h` is missing from the openssl folder and the make command raises the error:

```
 make: *** No rule to make target `/usr/include/openssl/opensslconf.h', needed by `.objs/rmd160.o'.  Stop.
```

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 on a 32 bit AMD laptop.

Update: I executed the following to cleanout my installation:

```
sudo apt-get remove libssl-dev build-essential g++-4.4 libboost-all-dev libsparsehash-dev git-core perl
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev build-essential g++-4.4 libboost-all-dev libsparsehash-dev git-core perl
git clone git://github.com/znort987/blockparser.git
cd blockparser
make
```

Now I get:

> /usr/include/openssl/e_os2.h:56:33: fatal error: openssl/opensslconf.h: No such file or directory

Answer (score 16):

If you're building on a 64-system and you're targeting 32-bit, the following command fixed this issue for me:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev:i386
```

Comment: And you need to activate this architecture first with `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`

Comment: apparently these packages aren't multilib compatible (on Debian buster anyway). installing the i386 versions removed the amd64.

Answer (score 4):

This stuff seems to have happened a long time ago (specifically, 2013-05-20 16:56:06 UTC).  I ran into a weird problem that looked very much like the OP, but it turned out to be a problem with swig failing to attach the right set of includes when compiling.  I ended up hunting through the source just to make sure it wasn't a ubuntu package problem, but it didn't seem to be an issue with ubuntu.

Looking more carefully into this, the openssl package shifted opensslconf.h into a multiarch-aware directory structure.  Here's the detailed commit: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/utopic/openssl/utopic-updates/revision/11.1.42 and if you want to see how I came up with that revision, I followed the annotated revisions of the debian rules which was a surprisingly efficient way to figure out what happened: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/utopic/openssl/utopic-updates/annotate/head:/debian/rules.

And the committer, Kurt Roeckx, writes in the Changelog:

> - Move  to /usr/include/$(DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH), and mark libssl-dev Multi-Arch: same.

To be fair, I wish the opensslconf.h was, at least, symlinked into the /usr/include/openssl folder with the rest of the logically related headers.  But that's not a bug, that's just my opinion.  To the folks that run into this problem like I did, it just takes a bit of sniffing out missing includes to keep things humming along.

And *to the OP*, it's quite a lot later now, but I just gave your exact set of steps a run through on a 14.04 LTS x64 box and didn't run into the problem you were having. Perhaps the problem was simply solved over time.  Hope some of this helps.

Comment: I think I'm having the same problem as you now. How did you solve it?

Answer (score 3):

> have executed sudo apt-get libssl-dev. I can see all sorts of ssl related header files in /usr/include/openssl but opensslconf.h is missing from the openssl folder and the make command raises the error ...

It sounds like the package is defective.

`<openssl/opensslconf.h>` is created by OpenSSL's `Configure` command. It should be included with the distro files. The earliest mention I could find was OpenSSL's [CHANGELOG at version 0.9.2](http://www.openssl.org/news/changelog.html).

File a bug report at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug/?no-redirect.

Answer (score 2):

I encoutered this issue while compiling  a setup meant for an embedded  LTS 14 device on LTS 16 PC. This is how I solved it:

```
 cd /usr/include/openssl/

 sudo ln -s /usr/include/gnutls/openssl.h .

 sudo ln -s ../x86_64-linux-gnu/openssl/opensslconf.h .
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's a problem with 32 vs. 64 bit systems. I cleared everything out, downloaded and built Openssl myself, and followed the instructions for building the parser. During the lnk phase it skipped the "incompatible libcrypto" and then failed.

So I am presuming that the required libraries are only available for 64 bit systems, and are skipped during the install of libssl-dev on 32 bit systems. A clearer error message would be nice.

Comment: I'm trying to compile a 32 bit program on a 64 bit machine and am getting the same `opensslconf.h` not found error. installed `libssl-dev` (is there a 32 bit version of that?) and all but my program doesn't compile because of the missing file. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It has moved because of multi arch.  On amd64 it's located in
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/openssl/opensslconf.h

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=733644