# Missing opensslconf.h when compiling GIT

Tags: apt, compiling, git, openssl

I decided to clone the git source into `/usr/src` and checked out to the latest stable version (since I currently have 1.9.1).  During the compiling I received a few errors regarding missing dependencies and swiftly fixed them by installing the development packages accordingly.

However, this time I had the latest development openssl libraries installed but I received the following error:

> fatal error: openssl/opensslconf.h: No such file or directory

I know this is a missing dependency so I proceed to install the latest/develop package for OpenSSL.

```
$ apt-cache search openssl | grep dev
$ apt-get install libssl-dev
```

Glorious, however I still receive the above error. A quick Google Search points me to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/523831/opensslconf-h-not-found) which is still unmarked and quite dated.

---

Below is the entire list of commands executed:

```
ash$ sudo su -
root# apt-get install git
root# git clone https://github.com/git/git.git && cd git
root# git checkout 2.7.0
root# less INSTALL 
root# make prefix=/usr install install-doc install-html install-info
root# apt-get install libssl-dev
root# make prefix=/usr install install-doc install-html install-info
root# apt-cache search expat | grep dev
root# apt-get install lib64expat1-dev
root# make prefix=/usr install install-doc install-html install-info
```

Answer (score 3):

When the following dependency is installed `lib64expat1-dev` many packages are replaced, some of which were 64bit specific.

The problem here is that `opensslconfig.h` has been moved into a different directory as can be seen below:

```
$ find / -type f -name opensslconf.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/openssl/opensslconf.h
```

Where as the compiler is searching for this file inside of `/usr/include` for it.  So simply creating a symbolic link will correct this dependency.

```
$ cd /usr/include/openssl
$ ln -s /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/openssl/opensslconf.h opensslconf.h
```